# @media only screen and (max-width:1280px), (min-height:801px) doesn't work

Tags: css, svg, media

I have css code that goes like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1280px){
  .numbertable {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right:12%;
    width:45%;
  }
  .gears {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right:10%;
    width:75%;
    top:15px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1280px), (min-height:801px){
  .numbertable {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right:12%;
    top:20px;
    width:65%;
  }
  .gears {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right:10%;
    width:75%;
    top:15px;
  }
}
```

According to how I understand it, if I'm using a resolution that is 1280px wide but BELOW 800px height, then the top code applies. But if the resolution is above height 800px then the bottom code should apply. This is not the case. I just tested this on a 1280x800 resolution, and the bottom code applied even though it says min-height 801px, it's like the min-height query is not taking effect, why is this?

Comment: It seems I've misunderstood how this works, I thought it was max-width AND min-height had to apply, but it appears it's max-width OR min-height. So the question is, is there a way to make an @media query where BOTH the max-width AND the min-height have to apply for it to take effect?

Comment: Ah that appears to have worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could just put `and` again instead of the comma :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (min-height: 801px) {

...

}
```